# Can I use the geocoding web-service to create another web-service to provide some free information?

Tags: web-services, google-maps, zipcode, postal-code

I developed a web-service that uses Google Maps API web-services to get the complete address of a zip-code in Brazil.

I created this service to give a free way to developers get complete address based on just the zip-code. That's because the government does not provide such service and neither the Postal Company. The Postal Company actually charges who wants this information and you actually have to download a database in MS Access that you have to download again in the future if you want up to date information, there is not even a charged online solution.

Hence, I just want to create this free service online based on Google Maps information, so I am not stealing data from the Postal Company.

My question is: is it allowed by Google Maps API terms and conditions? I read it but I could not find this situation.

Comment: Sounds like your question would be better asked to a mailing list/discussion forum for Google Maps API.  This site exists to answer specific programming problem questions not to answer legal queries like this, people here aren't lawyers and I would not recommend trusting any advice you did receive here without consulting a proper lawyer

Comment: mas a ideia e boa. nao desiste.

Comment: Thanks a lot RobV. At first moment I thought this was a Google's stuff because their web-site point to here saying they have users here and they monitor it. Would you know any form of contacting Google directly to have this answer? RASG... thanks!